# Rails spring goes into background and won't stop with `bin/spring stop`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spring, spring-boot

when running minitest,  I seem to have these background processes for spring that appear to get orphaned and don't seem to want to shut down when I run `bin/spring stop`

[image]

Comment: This isn't an answer, obviously, but have you tried just not using spring? I found that (a) these types of issues are a constant pain, and (b) boot-up is actually fairly fast these days, especially with Bootsnap involved. So I got rid of spring, after being a huge fan, a couple years ago and never looked back.

Comment: You know I agree with you and do generally turn Spring off.